# summarize_at and subsetting the grouped variable

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I achieve this with `summarize_at`?

**Data:**

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(100)
test_df <- data.frame(var_name=c(rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=3),"C"),
                      group_name=c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1),
                      obs_1=rnorm(10),
                      obs_2=rnorm(10))
```

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

```
test_df %>%
  group_by(var_name) %>%
  summarise(delta_obs1 = median(obs_1[group_name==1])-median(obs_1[group_name==0]),
            delta_obs2 = median(obs_2[group_name==1])-median(obs_2[group_name==0]),
            n_group1   = length(which(group_name==0)),
            n_group0   = length(which(group_name==1)))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  var_name delta_obs1 delta_obs2 n_group1 n_group0
    <fctr>      <dbl>      <dbl>    <int>    <int>
1        A -0.1064135  0.2947143        1        2
2        B -0.4857362 -0.2318824        2        1
3        C         NA         NA        0        4
```

However, this is rather messy and tedious if there are many columns (as in my real case).

**The `summarize_at` version which I cannot get to work:**

```
fun_obs_median <-
  function(x) {
    median(x[.$group_name == 1]) - median(x[.$group_name == 0])
  }

test_df %>%
  group_by(var_name) %>%
  summarize_at(.vars = colnames(.)[3:4],
               .funs=fun_obs_median)
```

`Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: object '.' not found.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(100)
test_df <- data.frame(var_name=c(rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=3),"C"),
                      group_name=c(1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1),
                      obs_1=rnorm(10),
                      obs_2=rnorm(10))

# function to calculate delta
delta_f = function(x) x[2]-x[1]

test_df %>%
  group_by(var_name, group_name) %>%                          # for each combination of var and group
  summarise_at(vars(matches("obs")), median) %>%              # get the median for all columns that match "obs"
  arrange(var_name, group_name) %>%                           # for each var get group == 0 in first row and group == 1 in second row
  summarise_at(vars(matches("obs")), funs(delta = delta_f))   # apply delta function

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   var_name obs_1_delta obs_2_delta
#   <fct>          <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 A             -0.106       0.295
# 2 B             -0.486      -0.232
# 3 C             NA          NA
```

Looks like the `arrange()` part is not necessary, as the grouping automatically order rows the way you want. But, it's good to keep that there in case that behaviour changes in the future due to a package update.

For the counts you can use this

```
test_df %>%
  mutate(group_name = paste0("n_group", group_name)) %>%
  count(var_name, group_name) %>%
  spread(group_name, n, fill = 0)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   var_name n_group0 n_group1
#   <fct>       <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 A               1        2
# 2 B               2        1
# 3 C               0        4
```

and then join the two tables by `var_name`.